# Get branch dependency from repository

Tags: git, github, composer-php

I would like to use the branch fcm from the github repository https://github.com/siwymilek/RMSPushNotificationsBundle

So in my `composer.json` I have:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/siwymilek/RMSPushNotificationsBundle"
    }
],
"require": {
    "siwymilek/RMSPushNotificationsBundle" : "dev-fcm",
}
```

But this is triggering this error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - The requested package siwymilek/rmspushnotificationsbundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

Comment: You should use package name from `composer.json`: https://github.com/siwymilek/RMSPushNotificationsBundle/blob/master/composer.json#L2

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, it's kind of tricky.

Looks like even if we are using a repository if this repository is forked, then we still have to use the name of the first repository, in my case I just replaced by `"richsage/rms-push-notifications-bundle" : "dev-fcm",`